# initializer list: a constructor from the base class and a member function

Tags: c++, list, constructor, explicit

So what I want to do is

initialize my subclass's constructor with my base class's constructor.

this is what my base class constructor looks like.

```
Appointment::Appointment(string description, int month, int day, int year, int hour, int minute):date(month, day, year){
    this-> hour = hour;
    this-> minute =minute;
    this-> description = description;
}
```

this is what my subclass constructor looks like

```
Daily::Daily(string description, int month, int day, int year, int hour, int minute) : Appointment(description, month, day, year, hour, minute){
}
```

^in my subclass's constructor (daily) there is an error that states that I need to explicitly initialize the member 'date', which does not have a default constructor.

How do I explicitly initialize both 'date' and 'Appointment' in my subclass constructor's initializer list?

Does it look something like this?

```
Daily::Daily(string description, int month, int day, int year, int hour, int minute) : Appointment(description, month, day, year, hour, minute):Date(month, day, year)
```

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Undeclared identifier? I thought I defined it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21156969/undeclared-identifier-i-thought-i-defined-it)

Comment: So both your base and derived classes have a different `date` data member?

Answer (score 1):

Considering `date` and `appointment`, using [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21156969/undeclared-identifier-i-thought-i-defined-it) you posted, to be as:

```
Date date;
Appointment appointment;
```

You can use this constructor syntax:

```
Daily::Daily(string description, int month, int day, int year, int hour, int minute) : appointment(description, month, day, year, hour, minute), date(month, day, year) { ... }
```

Usually in a definition like:

```
A::A(...) : x(...), y(...), ... {...}
```

`x(...), y(...), ...` is an *initializer-list* which purpose is to initialize member objects of the class.

Answer (score 0):

It should be comma separated

```
Daily::Daily(string description, int month, int day, int year, int hour, int minute) : Appointment(description, month, day, year, hour, minute), Date(month, day, year)
```

Answer (score 0):

if Daily class has a (Date) and has an (Appointment) which meanse it's a composition then you have to use the initializer list as shown below

```
Daily::Daily(string description, int month, int day, int year, int hour, int minute) :
   Appointment(description, month, day, year, hour, minute),
   Date(month, day, year) {}
```

but if Daily has an (Appointment) only -composition- and as i can see the Appointment has a (Date) -composition- then the Daily constructor should be like this

```
Daily::Daily(string description, int month, int day, int year, int hour, int minute) :
   Appointment(description, month, day, year, hour, minute) {}
```

and the Appoiintment parameterized constructor will call the Date parameterized constructor